# O que é code golf?

Tags: terminologia, code-golf

Olhando as tags do site, me deparo com a tag [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), li a breve explicação:

> **code-golf**
>   Utilize esta tag quando somente quando a pergunta tem uma relação
>   irrefutável à competição de código Code Golf. Tome muito cuidado ao
>   utilizar esta tag, pois este é um tema fácil de ter perguntas de
>   baixíssima qualidade. Code Golf é uma competição recreacional de
>   programação com o intuito de resolver um problema específico no menor
>   número de bytes, caracteres ou com algum tipo de restrição de código
>   fonte.
>   <sub>Fonte: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/code-golf/info</sub>

E gostaria de saber:

- O que é essa competição?
- Como seria um problema de uma competição *Code Golf*?
- Exemplo de uma resolução de um problema *Code Golf*?

Comment: Estou na dúvida se é melhor a pergunta ficar aqui ou no meta

Comment: [Codewar](https://www.codewars.com/) é isso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Definição de [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Code Golf é uma competição para resolver um problema específico no menor número, de bytes ou linhas de código.

> O termo *code golf* é derivado da semelhança de seu objetivo com o do golfe convencional, onde os participantes procuram alcançar a menor pontuação possível... Enquanto os jogadores de golfe convencional estão tentando minimizar a quantidade de golpes necessários para completar a partida, os *code golfers* estão se esforçando para reduzir o número de bytes de seus algoritmos.<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)</sup>

Puzzles (problemas) de programação precisam ser resolvidos (geralmente) com alguma restrição ou condição especial. Nessa competição pode se usar qualquer ferramenta disponível, desde que não vá contra as regras ditas no post.

---

### Exemplos

#### [Construir um relógio digital no Conway's Game of Life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88783/build-a-digital-clock-in-conways-game-of-life)

Veja um prelúdio do post:

> Sua tarefa é construir uma simulação Game of Life que represente um relógio digital:
>
> ## Objetivos
>
> - O relógio exibe as horas e os minutos em decimal (12:00, 3:59, 7:24)
> - O padrão é periódico, e o estado é acompanhado sem qualquer interação externa.
> - A atualização de minutos é em intervalos regulares
> - Os dígitos são visíveis e claramente distinguíveis.
> - A atualização dos dígitos é no lugar e devem aparecer  próximos uns dos outros
>
> ## Pontuação
>
> Seu programa será pontuado nas seguintes coisas, em ordem (com critérios mais baixos atuando como desempatadores para critérios mais altos):
>
> - Tamanho da caixa de encadernação
> - Execução mais rápida
> - Contagem inicial de células vivas
> - Primeiro a postar

#### Resultado final:

[image: Result]

[Via browser](https://copy.sh/life/?gist=f3413564b1fa9c69f2bad4b0400b8090&step=512) para você ver funcionando também.

---

#### [Era somente um bug](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129523/it-was-just-a-bug)

Outro code golf, um pouco diferente, o objetivo era conseguir desenvolver um algoritmo que *print*asse na tela, exatamente igual o texto abaixo:

```
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1234567890
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
```

A resposta aceita foi dada  utilizando uma [linguagem específica para *code golf*](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) stack-based. Foi essa abaixo, utilizando somente 13 bytes:

```
17F9ÝÀN8αð×ý,
```

Simples e em pouquíssimas linhas foi resolvido. Você pode ver como fica o [resultado aqui](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v8wNWFiMWX//zE3RjnDncOATjjOscOww5fDvSz//w).

Explicação abaixo:

```
17F            # para N em [0 ... 16] faça
   9Ý          # empurre de [0 ... 9]
     À         # virar esquerda
      N8α      # computa diferença absoluta entre N e 8
         ð×    # empurre esse tanto de espaços
           ý   # mescla a lista de dígitos com a seqüência de espaço como separador
            ,  # print
```

---

Todos esses e vários outros *code golf* podem ser encontrados na comunidade específica da SE em 
[Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score -4):

Segué a resposta:

> "Code golf é um tipo de competição recreacional de programação de computadores em que os participantes se esforçam para alcançar o código fonte mais curto possível que implemente um determinado algoritmo. Código de golfe não deve ser confundido com sizecoding, um concurso para alcançar o menor código binário executável. O código de reprodução de golfe é conhecido como "scripting de golfe". Os torneios de golfe de código também podem ser nomeados com a linguagem de programação usada (por exemplo, Perl golf)"

Fonte: wikipedia
Exemplo: www.code-golf.com/

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)